# Simple html button with #anchor on onClick window.location doesn´t work

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have this simple HTML button on my page:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location='http://localhost/test.php?param1=A&param2=B#MyANCHOR';"></button>
```

The problem: it executes the anchor command, positioning #MyANCHOR on top, but it doesn´t reload the page. It should execute the URL, reloading it and after it, then positioning the #MyANCHOR on top after it loads.

I spent some time looking for some solution here, but I wouldn't like to use jQuery on it, because I think I can reach my objective with a simple modification, mabe changing the onClick content, some simple detail, what else... suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you clicking the button from the same URL as what's in the onclick property?

Comment: Yes isherwood. Its a kind of "cancel modifications button". In the test.php I show this button, so the user can cancel modifications in the form, reloading the page, but after it reloads, position #MyAnchor on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the reason it doesn't reload the page is because you are already on the page when clicking the link. Add a cache buster

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location='http://localhost/test.php?param1=A&param2=B&cb=' + new Date().getTime() + '#MyANCHOR';">
```